# PHP foreach to Smarty

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I am trying to rewrite the RSS Feed Parser PHP Code to Smarty. The Smarty will not work for me somehow. Can somebody help me out please?

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($feed['items'] as $item): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?= $item['link']; ?>"><?= $item['title']; ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

**My Smarty Code** Updated: 12/07/13

```
{foreach name=aussen item=$feed.items from=$item}
    <li>
        <a href="{$item.link}">{$item.title}</a>
    </li>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Yes but I am not a Coder. Learning by doing and if people allow than by asking and getting reply for noobs. If you check the reputation -1 than you will ask yourself for what exist stackoverflow? Only for professionals to be Master Yoda?

Comment: You are expected to do some research, try to do it yourself, try to work it out - and come and ask questions as a last resort.

Comment: Oh yes you are right Aleks! "Try to do it yourself" For what is Stackoverflow? How you can know if this is not MY last resort or not? If I have had found the result why should I need you?!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with your smarty code.  First, and foremost, you should NOT have php logic and smarty formatting in the same file. You should assign smarty variables separately and then call smarty for formatting.  However if you stick with your existing stuff, you'll need to take into account the following:

1. syntax of your `foreach` is wrong - the correct syntax is `{foreach from=$variable item=$loop_var}`
2. php variables are not automatically available in smarty - you'll need to add smarty `{assign} directive with a combination of`{php}echo $php_var{/php}` to get php variable to smarty.
3. syntax `{php}$item['title']{/php}` is invalid syntax for php and will result in syntax error.

On the whole, your approach is flawed.  Smarty is good for a presentation (view) layer in an MVC app - and you're trying to combine everything into one file.  Don't.  If you are not sure how to set your application properly as MVC, then smarty is not for you.

Comment: I want to implent it into a Smarty Based CMS. Thats why trying to rewrite it in Smarty.